# `*buf` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop?

Tags: rust

This code:

```rust
pub struct Event<'a> {
    _p: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

pub fn foo<'a>(_buf: &'a mut Vec<u8>) -> Event<'a> {
    todo!()
}

pub fn bar<'a>(buf: &'a mut Vec<u8>, event: &'a mut Event<'a>) {
    loop {
        *event = foo(buf);
    }
}
```

Compile error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*buf` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:11:22
   |
9  | pub fn bar<'a>(buf: &'a mut Vec<u8>, event: &'a mut Event<'a>) {
   |            -- lifetime `'a` defined here
10 |     loop {
11 |         *event = foo(buf);
   |                  ----^^^-
   |                  |   |
   |                  |   `*buf` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
   |                  argument requires that `*buf` is borrowed for `'a`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

But remove the `loop`, the code will be passed, I want to know why to fix this compile error.

Comment: How does your `Event` struct relate to the buffer in your code? Does it reference the buffer in any way? I believe the error in your example is caused by the same lifetime being used everywhere but the solution will depend on the above question.

Answer (score 3):

In the example you give, the compiler error is correct in terms of safety. In the first iteration, the buffer is passed into Event and then stored in `*event`. The next iteration cannot loan the buffer to as it is still owned by `*event`.

If however `Event` doesn't actually reference the buffer after the fact, you can introduce a new lifetime to show that:

```rust
pub struct Event<'a> {
    _p: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

pub fn foo<'a, 'b>(_buf: &'a mut Vec<u8>) -> Event<'b> {
    todo!()
}

pub fn bar<'a>(buf: &'a mut Vec<u8>, event: &'a mut Event<'a>) {
    loop {
        *event = foo(buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fn foo<'b>() -> Foo<'b>` is very often wrong. This means: _"whatever lifetime the caller chooses, `foo` will return an instance with this lifetime"_, but there is no way for `foo` to construct a value with an arbitrary lifetime. The only case where this will work is if `foo` returns an instance that doesn't actually use the provided lifetime, e.g. `fn foo<'b>() -> Option<&'b i32> { None }` or `fn foo<'b>() -> Option<&'b i32> { Some(&1) }` (the latter case uses a `'static` lifetime that can be cast implicitly to `'b`).

Comment: @Jmb It is also sometimes used with raw pointers, though in this case the function has to be marked `unsafe`. Generally, you should use that only if you can to the same extent mark your function as returning `'static`.