# cannot return value referencing local variable when constructing a structure

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```
struct WordleWords<'a> {
    words: Vec<&'a str>,
}

impl WordleWords<'_> {
    pub fn new<'a>() -> WordleWords<'a> {
        let mut word_file = File::open("words.txt").expect("cant open file");
        let mut raw_str = String::new();
        word_file
            .read_to_string(&mut raw_str)
            .expect("cant read file");;
        WordleWords { words: raw_str.split('\n').collect() }
    }
}
```

Hi, so I am new to rust programming. I am trying to make a copycat of the viral wordle game to become better with rust. I can't figure out how to work around this error `cannot return value referencing local variable raw_str` I keep getting with this line `WordleWords { words: raw_str.split('\n').collect() }`

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71869990/buf-was-mutably-borrowed-here-in-the-previous-iteration-of-the-loop/71870389#comment127004538_71870389

Answer (score 1):

Lets look closer at the function `new`. You are creating local variable `raw_str` - a variable that will be deleted when the function finishes. However,  `new` returns an isntance of `WordleWords` that contains a reference to `raw_str`. This is will create an issue known as dangling pointer - a pointer to a memory location that has been freed. The compiler is smart enough to prevent you from doing so.

The easiest fix would be to store a `Vec<String>` instead of a `Vec<&'a str>`

```
struct WordleWords {
    words: Vec<String>,
}

impl WordleWords {
    pub fn new() -> WordleWords {
        let mut word_file = File::open("words.txt").expect("cant open file");
        let mut raw_str = String::new();
        word_file
            .read_to_string(&mut raw_str)
            .expect("cant read file");

        WordleWords {
            words: raw_str.split('\n').map(|i| i.to_string()).collect(),
        }
    }
}
```

*EDIT:*

If you insist on using references, you would have to store `raw_str` inside your struct, and return `Pin<Box<WordleWords<'a>>>` from `new`.

```
struct WordleWords<'a> {
    raw_str: String,
    words: Vec<&'a str>,
    _pin: PhantomPinned,
}

impl<'a> WordleWords<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Pin<Box<WordleWords<'a>>> {
        let mut word_file = File::open("words.txt").expect("cant open file");
        let mut raw_str = String::new();
        word_file
            .read_to_string(&mut raw_str)
            .expect("cant read file");

        let wordle_words = WordleWords {
            raw_str,
            words: vec![],
            _pin: PhantomPinned,
        };

        let mut boxed = Box::pin(wordle_words);

        // let words = boxed.raw_str.split('\n').collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let raw_str_ref = NonNull::from(&boxed.raw_str);

        unsafe {
            let mut_ref: Pin<&mut Self> = Pin::as_mut(&mut boxed);
            Pin::get_unchecked_mut(mut_ref).words =
                raw_str_ref.as_ref().split('\n').collect::<Vec<_>>();
        }

        boxed
    }
}
```

Here is the basic idea:

- `raw_string` needs to be stored somewhere that it won't get deleted - inside the instance of `WordleWords` itself.
- This causes `WordleWords` to be self referencing - a potentially unsafe architecture because if your instance is being moved from one place in memory to another, the self reference will be invalidated.
- To fix this, `Box` and `Pin` are introduced - the combination of these two structs ensures that the data they store will never be moved to a different memory location.

for more info: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The `str::split()` method returns an iterator over *borrowed slices* of an owned string.  This is efficient as it requires no copying, but it means that the values aren't owned and have their lifetime tied to something else (`raw_str` in this case).

In order to fix this, you need to convert them from borrowed slices (`&str`) to an owned value (`String`) which you can do with various methods (`.to_string()`, `.to_owned()`).  So the way you address this is by mapping the split iterator over this method:

```
WordleWords { words: raw_str.split('\n').map(|v| v.to_owned()).collect() }
```

This requires changing the definition of your struct to:

```
struct WordleWords {
    words: Vec<String>,
}
```

Always remember that a borrowed value requires an owned value to live somewhere to borrow from.  If the borrow outlives the value being borrowed from, you get this compile-time error.